# How to write a pmatrix such that each line and column could be labeled?

Tags: matrices

There were many cases of how to write block diagonal matrix. However, how to write a pmatrix such that the line and column could be labeled?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Did you try to do a searcho for `matrix` and `label`?

Comment: You can see the `blkarray`  package.

Comment: @Bernard is there a way to just use amsmath etc.? there's been to many packages and some of them were not quite compatible with each other.

Comment: It has no incompatibility I know of. It's a small package which loads `array`, and it works fine within `amsmath`.

Comment: @Bernard blkarray isn't based on array package at all it is a completely separate tabular implementation (and 2227 lines long, although a lot comments of course)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Sorry, I didn't check. I simply remembered it happened that some commands I used didn't work without array, but worked with blkarray, from which I thought I could deduce it loaded array, all the more so as you're one of the authors of array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is very easy with `nicematrix`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{pNiceMatrix}[last-col,last-row]
a_{1} & a_{2} & l_{1} \\
a_{3} & a_{4} & l_{2} \\
c_{1} & c_2
\end{pNiceMatrix}
\]

\end{document}
```

This requires several LaTeX runs at the beginning, but the typesetting will soon stabilize.

[image]